# Apache does not pick up default index file when I enter domain name

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I installed an ubuntu server 16.04 and LAMP, it works very well and I can load default web by using ip address.

Also I created a new virtual host by domain synappse.ir. If I enter synappse.ir/index.html, it loads the page and there is not any issue but when I enter just the name of the domain without index.php, it can not find or load the index.html file!

Here is my config file for virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerNamei
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin nasser.man@gmail.com
        ServerName synappse.ir
        ServerAlias synappse.ir
        DocumentRoot /var/www/synappse.ir
        DirectoryIndex index.html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #<Directory /var/www/html>
        #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #       AllowOverride All
        #       Require all granted
        #</Directory>

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any other configuration for enabling this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, pages were cached, every thing is ok.